# configure apache 2.2 to avoid 504 error in blackberry devices

Tags: apache-2.2, web, blackberry

I deploy an application to a local instance of Apache. This web app is for mobile devices. The app works well on an iphone or android, but from BlackBerry devices I get a 504 error. Do I need another configuration on the Apache side of things for this devices, or do I need to configure the BlackBerry to handle this error?

Answer (score 0):

The http/504 is a time-out error, do you know where this error occur? I can imagine that the BB application somehow uses a proxy before reaching your Apache, and that the Apache in turn is forwarding the request to something else (eg. Tomcat). If that's the case, your timeout can occur at many places.

The first thing I would do is to fire up Wireshark at the machine where your Apache is running and take a close look at the network communication. Are there anything suspicious going on? Can you find differences between the iPhone and BB requests? If so, I'd suggest adding that information to your question here.

Good luck!